# Java swt KeyListener "solution" barcode reading

Tags: java, swt, barcode-scanner, keylistener

I found some good Q/A here on my problem but couldn't find the right one.

I have a [barcode reader](http://www.honeywellaidc.com/en-US/Pages/Product.aspx?category=hand-held-barcode-scanner&cat=HSM&pid=5145) that reads barcode and sends scanned code as keyboard input. It is alright I can catch input easily

```
browser.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {   
    @Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.keyCode >=48 && e.keyCode <=57) {
            System.out.println("number caught");
        } 
    }
});
```

But I will have more inputs in my application so I need to know if it is send by barcode reader or by keyboard. 
I think it can be achieved by adding some timer in code that verifies how long is some "sequence" reading.

I just can not figure it out, (I mean logic behind it), I am missing piece of logic.

1. User is typing some info, (alpha numerical)
2. user desides to use barcode reader to read barcode

I tried timer e.g 
`if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastPressProcessed ??? 500) {` after keyListener is triggered but I think I am missing something.

*sidenote:*
USB barcode reads code fast so keystrokes are emulated really fast est whole barcode is written in about 1 second + carry `/r/n` (also `enter` is pressed).

*sidenote2:* barcodes are going to be different in length so I can not read just some length in short time and decide wether it is user input or barcode input (max numbers read  13 + `enter`).

*sidenote3:* I have no input field for barcode I am trying to achieve running it on "background".

I am seeking **logic/pseudocode suggestions** on topic.

related topics that are really close to mine are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5199636/1564365), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969324/1564365)

Thank you.

**edit**

After deep tought I found out the solution I'll keep this Q here just for another users that might find this usable.

**solution**
--moved to answer + edited

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer and select it if it solved your problem. However, I don't think your code does what you think it does. You say "whole barcode is written in about 1 second", but your code allows for 1 second to elapse between two keystrokes and still treats the input as scanner input! "I have no input field for barcode", do you have other input fields and you are trying to prevent scanned data from going into those fields?

Comment: Whenever is /r/n passed to program  loop is "closed" so barcode is read. I changed time to 200 ms, I was worried about system "lag". I think this code meets my needs I know its not perfect but in this matter it is I ll update my solution because I made some changes also. I know I can post answers but I have to wait 2 (1?) days to accept it. There is not going to be a Java input, but HTML one. The Java program is there just to read barcodes and send them to webpage.

Comment: Also I am not worried about mixing users manual input with barcodes. While in "editing" mode barcode scanner is going to be "turned off" (in software matter).  Please make more suggestions if you feel its needed.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22084579/320594 for an alternative (although not ready for production)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code coveres everything I wanted to achieve, it reads just numbers (actualy numbers that are under F keys, not numbers that are on numpad, I had problem with it because scanner is keyboard dependant so I made function `signsToNumbers()` that converts signs `!@#$%^&*()` to numbers `1234567890`. I may change this function because every key on keyboard has its own unique identifier + modifier, it seems that scanner sends also SHIFT modifier to the application but that is not as problem as it seems I'll just match `e.keyCode`.

The code below works as:

1. waits for number input otherwise does nothing
2. if 1st number is inserted it is looping in `if` condition until either 200ms is reached or '\r\n` is received
3. sends data to server via URL

**code**

```
@Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (timer == true && System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimer < 200) {
      if(e.keyCode >=48 && e.keyCode <=57) { //number pressed
          lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
          myString = myString + Character.toString(e.character);
        }
        if(e.keyCode == SWT.CR) {
          myString = signsToNumbers(myString);
          newUrl = browser.getUrl()+ "/newcode/" + myString;
          browser.setUrl(newUrl);
          text.setText(newUrl);
          System.out.println(myString);
          System.out.println("barcode read");
          myString = "";
          timer = false;
          lastTimer = 0;
        }
    }else{
        if(e.keyCode >=48 && e.keyCode <=57) {
          lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
          timer = true;
          myString = Character.toString(e.character);
        }
        myString = "";
        lastTimer = 0;
    }        
  }
});
```

Comment: Please provide your answer with the timer itself!

Comment: What do you mean? I use system timer.

Comment: I think it would be cool if you could expand your answer with additional timer en timertask.

Comment: I am sorry, this is 2 years old :(, I dont have actual code anymore, feel free to expand answer. This was one time java job, I am unskilled in java.

Comment: It's fine! Thanks for your fast response :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you can download my solution:

http://jhead.hu/resource/java/general/BarcodeReader.java

The following code sample shows you, how to use it. When a new barcode is identified, an ActionEvent is generated and you can get the barcode via the getActionCommand() method. If the panel is not active you can send the characters further to the focus manager.

The only problem is that my barcode scanner sends the characters too fast so the character bits are sometimes mixed. I've got no better solution yet.

```
public class PanelWithBarcodeReading extends javax.swing.JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private BarcodeReader barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();

    public PanelWithBarcodeReading() {
        initComponents();
        barcodeReader.addActionListener(this);
        barcodeReader.setParent(this);
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(barcodeReader);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this).isActive()) {
            System.out.println("BARCODE='" + e.getActionCommand() + "'");
        } else {
            barcodeReader.dispatchLastBarcodeAsKeyEvents();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```